# .htaccess: redirecting URLs containing /../

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have several URLs like this:

`http://site.com/knowndir/../somedir/page.html`

I need to redirect them to

`http://site.com/somedir/page.html`

Basically, I need to remove the `knowndir/../` particle from the URL. I know the `knowndir` part.

So far, I've tried with this rule:

`RewriteRule knowndir\/\.\.\/(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]` but without any luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the client already removes the `.` and `..` path elements. You can see the difference in the Apache `access.log`, when you request a page with firefox or wget vs requesting a URL with telnet and `GET /knowndir/../somedir/page.html HTTP/1.0`.

When, despite that, Apache receives a request with `.` and `..` path elements, Apache already takes care of that by itself, without the need for any redirect rules. This means it resolves these segments by removing `.` or `subdir/..`, in order to get an unambiguous path.

So, in the end your RewriteRule never sees `knowndir/../` and thus will not send a `301` redirect.

**Update**:

I finally found the relevant [RFC 3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2), which describes in [5.2.4.  Remove Dot Segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) how `.` and `..` should be handled.

OT: Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.

Comment: @SilviuG What do you see int the browser's URL bar? In my test environment this works properly.

Comment: In the address bar I see the right URL: `http://site.com/somedir/page.html`. However, when testing the URLs with SamSpade I get a `200` response code and the page in question. **Note:** the right URL was shown by my browser (Firefox) even before I attempted the redirects. It seems that the browser understands the URL and corrects it.

Comment: @SilviuG Which response do you expect and why?

Comment: I expect a `301` and a `Location: ` header

Comment: Hmm... the question was asked because I have some `/knowndir/../somedir/page.html` pages in GWT for a site (composed of a bunch of HTML files, no CMS), and I was looking to do a 301 redirect for those wrong links (all the links are relative, that's why the `../` is used), and I don't know how to search for them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SilviuG If the client already removes `..`, there's no way to find them. But if there are clients wich don't remove them (I tested with firefox and wget only), you can search through your log files for `..`. Maybe you will find some requests there.